# Elasticsearch query shows wrong results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using below query to get the elastic search results in php.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "q= (\"Agriculture\" OR \"Agribusiness\" OR \"Agriculture\") et_tax= \"Agriculture\" -et_tax:\"Agriculture\"" 
        }
      }
    }
  },
 "aggs": {
    "lawfirmcount": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "pd_lawfirmID",
        "precision_threshold": 1250 
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

When is use the above code, it will fetch unmatched results. Is there anything wrong in that query.

Comment: At first glance, the `=` signs in your query should be colons `:`

Comment: I have replaced the `=` as `:`, but following query not working  `"query": "q:(\"Agriculture\" OR \"Agribusiness\")"`

Comment: Note that you also have a second equal sign (`et_tax=`). How does your mapping type look like? Please share it

Comment: Please check the below URL `http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://pptssolutionsdemo.com:9200/_all/_mapping/`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are querying on the same field, `et_tax`, twice. In the first case, where the term "Agriculture" is present, and then again where "Agriculture" is not present (`-et_tax:`). I would expect this to return all documents, since the term "Agriculture" either exists or does not exist in the field `et_tax`, and the default operator for `query_string` is `OR`.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) for `query_string`. You can change the `default_operator` to be `AND` instead.

Also, I suggest removing the double quotes from your search values, assuming they are not part of the term you are searching on.

Finally, I don't see a `q` field in your mapping. I don't think the "q=" in your query is working as you are expecting. You probably need to remove that and specify a `default_field` to query against.

Hope this helps...